# Mock Apache HTTPClient with ResponseHandler in Mockito

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, apache-httpcomponents

I've been trying to mock Apache HTTPClient with ResponseHandler, in order to test my service, using Mockito. The method in question is:

```
String response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, responseHandler);
```

where "responseHandler" is a ResponseHandler:

```
ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = response -> {
    int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if (status == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    } else {
        log.error("Accessing API returned error code: {}, reason: {}", status, response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
        return "";
    }
};
```

Can somebody suggest how can I accomplish this? I want to mock "execute()" method, but I don't want to mock the "responseHandler" (I wan't to test the existing one).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can mock `HttpClient` and use Mockito's `thenAnswer()` method. For example, something like:

```
@Test
public void http_ok() throws IOException {
    String expectedContent = "expected";

    HttpClient httpClient = mock(HttpClient.class);
    when(httpClient.execute(any(HttpUriRequest.class), eq(responseHandler)))
            .thenAnswer((InvocationOnMock invocation) -> {
                BasicHttpResponse ret = new BasicHttpResponse(
                        new BasicStatusLine(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK, "OK"));
                ret.setEntity(new StringEntity(expectedContent, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                ResponseHandler<String> handler
                        = (ResponseHandler<String>) invocation.getArguments()[1];
                return handler.handleResponse(ret);
            });

    String result = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(), responseHandler);

    assertThat(result, is(expectedContent));
}
```

Comment: What is 'responseHandler' in eq(responseHandler)? I don't see it defined anywhere.
Could you please elaborate? Thanks...

Comment: It is the `responseHandler` variable as defined by @Zmaja in the question. The way I wrote the test assumes it is is defined as as instance variable in the test class, but of course you can define it as a local variable.

Comment: Thanks for the response!
In that case, would it not pass the response to responseHandler defined by us ( in our test class or test method locally)?
And, the actual responseHandler defined in main class would never be called and would be left from the coverage. Am I missing something?

Comment: The `responseHandler` is the object being tested. The one in the original question is just an example, and the test I wrote simply illustrates how to mock an `HTTPClient` which calls its `handleResponse` method. In the real world, the example should be adapted using the actual `ResponseHandler` being tested.

Comment: ok. I also have unit test scenario, where I have mocked execute method, but want to call actual responseHandler. Will try to make use of your code. Thanks!